# calculate percentage between columns in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have long tab formatted file with many columns, i would like to calculate % between two columns (3rd and 4rth) and print this % with correspondence numbers with this format (%46.00).

input:

```
file1   323     434     45      767     254235  275     2345    467
file1   294     584     43      7457    254565  345     235445  4635
file1   224     524     4343    12457   2542165 345     124445  41257
```

Desired output:

```
file1   323     434(134.37%)    45(13.93%)      767     254235  275     2345    467
file1   294     584(198.64%)    43(14.63%)      7457    254565  345     235445  4635
file1   224     524(233.93%)    4343(1938.84%)  12457   2542165 345     124445  41257
```

i tried:

```
cat test_file.txt |  awk '{printf "%s (%.2f%)\n",$0,($4/$2)*100}' OFS="\t" | awk '{printf "%s (%.2f%)\n",$0,($3/$2)*100}' | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$11,$4,$10,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9}' - | sed 's/ (/(/g' | sed 's/ /\t/g' >out.txt
```

It works but I want something sort-cut of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say:

```
$ awk '{$3=sprintf("%d(%.2f%)", $3, ($3/$2)*100); $4=sprintf("%d(%.2f%)", $4, ($4/$2)*100)}1' file
file1 323 434(134.37%) 45(13.93%) 767 254235 275 2345 467
file1 294 584(198.64%) 43(14.63%) 7457 254565 345 235445 4635
file1 224 524(233.93%) 4343(1938.84%) 12457 2542165 345 124445 41257
```

With a function to avoid duplicities:

```
awk 'function print_nice (num1, num2) {
        return sprintf("%d(%.2f%)", num1, (num1/num2)*100)
     }
     {$3=print_nice($3,$2); $4=print_nice($4,$2)}1' file
```

This uses `sprintf` to express a specific format and store it in a variable. The calculations are the obvious.

Comment: Thank for your elegant answer :)  but tell me, is it necessary to pass that function too ???

Comment: No, not really. It is just a way to avoid changing the `sprintf` flags every time in two places in case you want to change it.

Comment: To avoid redundancy and the function you can just do `awk '{for(i=3;i<5;i++)$i=sprintf("%d(%.2f%)", $i, ($i/$2)*100)}1'`

Comment: @JID absolutely amazing solution :)) thanks a million.